# Specify multiple parameters file for an ARM

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, azure-rm-template

I have a solution consisting of different services I need to deploy in my Azure account:

`global_params.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "globalParam1": {
            "value": "v1"
        },
        "globalParam2": {
            "value": "v2"
        }
    }
}
```

`myservice_params.json`:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "svcParam1": {
            "value": "v1"
        },
        "svcParam2": {
            "value": "v2"
        },
        "svcParam3": {
            "value": "v3"
        }
    }
}
```

In my ARM template `azuredeploy.json` I need to get both groups of parameters:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "globalParam1": {...}
    },
    "globalParam2": {...}
    },
    "svcParam1": {...}
    },
    "svcParam2": {...}
    },
    "svcParam3": {...}
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('globalParam1')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('svcParam1')]",
        "tier": "[parameters('svcParam2')]"
      },
      "kind": "[parameters('svcParam3')]",
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "[parameters('globalParam2')]"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I use the Azure CLI to make sure I pass parameters merged from both parameters file? I know one parameter file can be passed as follow (see [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files#deploy-template-with-parameter-file)):

```
az deployment group create ... --template-file ./azuredeploy.json --parameters @myservice_params.json
```

But how to specify two parameters files and get them merged?

Answer (score 0):

The CLI (nor Azure itself) support this - you would have to do the merge yourself prior to calling into Azure.

You could use defaultValues on the parameters in the template to come close to replicating.

Answer (score 0):

Although article is few months old, I tested it by adding second parameters file using @.
So command will be:

```
az deployment group create -g resourceGroup --template-file template.json --parameters @parameters1.json @parameters2.json
```